# Spatial location of the patent plate using CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am developing a project that deals with the detection of vehicle license plates with convolutional neural networks.

Within all the documents I have searched, it is based on 3 important phases:
1. Spatial location of the vehicle.
2. Spatial location of the patent plate.
3. Segmentation and character recognition.

It turns out that I did the first part, attached link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14kX2bjc8gmOZt9Ml3CGEkD9e7Z41sF_S

Now I need some advice on how to continue with the second step for the spatial location of the patent plate, should I use CNN too? If so, how could it be done?

I plan to retrain CNN within the last 'if' statement (where recognize if the image contains a vehicle or not) using some data sets with only images of patent plates.

Any help is received, thanks!

Comment: Your question is too general. You can start by reading this article about object detection using Keras: https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-r-cnn-object-detection-implemented-by-keras-for-custom-data-from-googles-open-images-125f62b9141a